# How to use deriving Show() in mutually recursive types?

Tags: ocaml, deriving, ocsigen

Let's directly see the codes.

```
type symbol =
   | JumpDes of int 
   | CallDes of func
   | StarDes of exp (*here needs the definition of type exp*)
  deriving (Show)
type exp =
   | Const of const
   | Symbol of symbol (*here needs the definition of type symbol*)
   | Reg of reg
   | Assist of assistop
   | Ptr of ptraddr
   | Label of string
   deriving (Show)
```

I'd like to use package [deriving](https://github.com/ocsigen/deriving/) to print info about the two types. According to its [document](https://ocsigen.org/deriving/latest/manual/intro), i just need to add `deriving (Show)` after types i want to print. But i can not define mutually recursive types by adding `and` like this:

```
type symbol =
   | JumpDes of int
   | CallDes of func
   | StarDes of exp 
  deriving (Show)
and exp = (*note that it's line 240*)
   | Const of const
   | Symbol of symbol
   | Reg of reg
   | Assist of assistop 
   | Ptr of ptraddr
   | Label of string
   deriving (Show)
```

Compiling codes above will get error below:

```
File "type.ml", line 240, characters 16-17:
Parse error: [semi] expected after [str_item] (in [implem])
File "type.ml", line 1:
Error: Error while running external preprocessor
```

How should i do if i'd like to use deriving Show() on mutually recursive types? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unless you're relying very heavily on the Ocsigen framework, which nothing about your question suggests, you should probably be using [`ppx_deriving`](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving) instead.

Comment: Are you using eliom-distillery? If you don't even know what is it, then probably you should better use ppx_deriving as suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But ppx_deriving does not solve the problem. I've saw a similar question on issue page [Customize printing of one of the mutually recursive types in deriving show](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving/issues/184)

Comment: Let me ask again. Are you married to Ocsigen and eliom or you just googled that page and want to use some deriving plugin? If the latter, I can provide an answer that will show how to use ppx_deriving to derive the show function. If the former, then we need more info, in particular how you build your code and whether you're using the distillery.

Comment: @ivg Actually the latter one. i'm confused with using something after declarations of types which depends on each other recursively. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To derive pretty-printing functions you can use [ppx_deriving](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving)<sup>1</sup>. First of all, make sure that you have it installed,

```
opam install ppx_deriving
```

Next, let's create a sample project based on your input,

```
type func = string [@@deriving show]
type const = int [@@deriving show]
type reg = int [@@deriving show]
type assistop = int [@@deriving show]
type ptraddr = int [@@deriving show]

type symbol =
  | JumpDes of int
  | CallDes of func
  | StarDes of exp
[@@deriving show]

and exp =
  | Const of const
  | Symbol of symbol
  | Reg of reg
  | Assist of assistop
  | Ptr of ptraddr
  | Label of string
[@@deriving show]


let () =
  let input = StarDes (Const 1) in
  Format.printf "%s\n%a@\n" (show_symbol input) pp_symbol input
```

I put some aliases for the types that you didn't provide in your question. Notice that all the types had to specify `[@@deriving show]`. When a type is recursive, just treat `and` as `type`. Basically, the same as you did, but we need to use the ppx-syntax, e.g., `[@@deriving show]` not the Ocsigen one.

At the end of the program, there is an example that shows how to use the generated functions. There are two types of function, `show_foo` which translates a value of type `foo` into the string, and the pretty-printing function `pp_foo` that prints `foo` into the formatter, which is faster since there is no need to create an intermediate string. The printers are used with the `%a` specifier and take two arguments, the printer itself and the value to print. So there's no need to put parentheses, also a small win. I used both options in the example, so that you can contrast them.

Finally, how to build it? If you're using `dune`, then here's the sample `dune` file,

```
(executable
 (name example)
 (preprocess
  (pps ppx_deriving.show)))
```

You can create the `dune` file yourself or use the following command (assuming that our program is in the `example.ml` file),

```
dune init executable example --ppx=ppx_deriving.show
```

You can run example with,

```
dune exec ./example.exe
```

If you're using `ocamlbuild` instead of dune, then just add `-package ppx_deriving.show` to your `ocamlbuild` invocation, e.g.,

```
ocamlbuild -package ppx_deriving.show example.native
./example.native
```

Both will print,

```
(Example.StarDes (Example.Const 1))
(Example.StarDes (Example.Const 1))
```

If you're using some other build system, then don't hesitate to ask, we will need more information about your build system or a link to your project. If you just starting a new project and don't know which build system you should use, then dune is the answer.

---

<sup>1)</sup>This is not the only option. You can also use ppx_jane's sexp deriver, ppx_show, and probably there are a few more.

Comment: if i'm using ocamlbuild to build the project, how to use ocamlfind to find packages used automatically instead of list out them in the terminal?

Comment: It is not possible, neither with ocamlbuild nor with dune or any other known to me build systems. You always have to specify the dependencies manually.